# Place nav-pills in card-header and tab-content in card-body using ngbTabSet

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I'd like to place **nav-pills in card-header** and **tab-content in card-body** using **ngbTabSet**. But I don't get on how to do this.

Here is a sample of what I try to achieve (using bootstrap.js)

[image: Sample]

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what I already tried (using ng-bootstrap)

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <ngb-tabset type="pills">
            <ngb-tab title="Home">
                <ng-template ngbTabContent>..</ng-template>
            </ngb-tab>
        </ngb-tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I end up with having everything inside **card-header**.
[image: Sample with ng-bootstrap]

Same when using template ref

```html
<ng-template ngbTabContent>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template_ref"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

I am using **bootstrap 4.0**, **ng-bootstrap 2.0** and **Angular 5.2**

Anyone having an idea on how to get this working?

Comment: We pulled the ngb-tabset and ngb-tab source into our project for similar reasons, Angular can't always keep up to the "extend instead of modify" princliple

Comment: I decided to do the same. Another thing I don't like about ng-bootstrap is the lack of animations :|. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 3):

**It is not possible to achieve this with ng-bootstrap 2.0. The template for the ngbTabset does not allow this.**

I decided to create my own tabset based on ngbTabset and customized their template.

---

Here my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'card-tabset',
    templateUrl: './card-tabset.component.html',
})
export class CardTabsetComponent extends NgbTabset {

    constructor(config: NgbTabsetConfig) {
        super(config);
    }
}
```

And the template

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul [class]="'nav nav-' + type + (orientation == 'horizontal'?  ' ' + justifyClass : ' flex-column')" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
        <a [id]="tab.id" class="nav-link" [class.active]="tab.id === activeId" [class.disabled]="tab.disabled" href (click)="!!select(tab.id)"
          role="tab" [attr.tabindex]="(tab.disabled ? '-1': undefined)" [attr.aria-controls]="(!destroyOnHide || tab.id === activeId ? tab.id + '-panel' : null)"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="tab.id === activeId" [attr.aria-disabled]="tab.disabled">
          {{tab.title}}
          <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tab.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <ng-template ngFor let-tab [ngForOf]="tabs">
        <div class="tab-pane {{tab.id === activeId ? 'active' : null}}" *ngIf="!destroyOnHide || tab.id === activeId" role="tabpanel"
          [attr.aria-labelledby]="tab.id" id="{{tab.id}}-panel" [attr.aria-expanded]="tab.id === activeId">
          <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tab.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked very well for me via Angular 8 and `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do that with ng-bootstrap. I've encountered the same problem with other ng-bootstrap components that doesn't replicate exactly the behaviour of bootstrap.

However, I think you can easily accomplish that functionality with raw bootstrap and Angular,  with `ngSwitch` for example.

More info on ngSwitch: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

The unclosed thread of this feature: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1567

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I decided to pull tabset source into my project and create my own template for it.